# Importing XML file to Excel shows only root

Tags: xml, excel

I am trying to import an XML file into Excel. The file is basically a sitemap, where it's just a tree of all the pages. If, under the Data tab, I use the "From Web" option (the file comes from an API online), the import only comes back with the headers and the root node, while ignoring the other 3000+ pages.

I believe the problem stems from how subpages are represented. The home page has a subpages element that contains all the lower pages, and those lower pages all have subpages, too. I think Excel is just ignoring the subpages (maybe it doesn't know what to do with it).

[Here is a picture of the top of the XML file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWyHx.png)

Thank you in advance for any assistance. I am really having trouble even finding anyone else with this issue in online help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have figured out a solution. I'll do my best to explain it.

First of all, let me restate the problem in a general way (it leaves out some specifics). I had a root data node with one of the fields being a table that contained more nodes of the same type. These new nodes also had tables of same-type nodes, and this could go on forever. When importing with Power Query/Excel, only the root node would show. I could click the table cell and see the next level down, but not everything at the same time.

What I needed to do was extract the contents of these sub-tables and append them onto the bottom of the existing table, and to do this for every single row in the table (including these freshly added nodes). If you're familiar with searching algorithms, you can visualize it as a breadth-first search (not really important, but helped me).

One helpful article/code to copy was from this link: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/05/21/expanding-all-columns-in-a-table-in-power-query/

This is not the solution, but similar (and mine is based on it). It expands columns horizontally, while I wanted the contents appended vertically.

Finally, here is the code for the solution. It is a Power Query function that you can call, with the input being the table to expand. Please note that a lot of this solution is specific to my problem, and that you will need to edit it if you need to use it. I put some notes for things you will probably need to change in stars in the comments.

```
let
//Define function
Source = (TableToExpand as table, optional RowNumber as number) =>
    let
    //We only want subpages column, *you will need to change this*
    ActualColumnNumber = 6,

    //RowNumber starts at 0 by default
    ActualRowNumber = if (RowNumber=null) then 0 else RowNumber,

    //Find the column name relating to the column number
    ColumnName = Table.ColumnNames(TableToExpand){ActualColumnNumber},

    //Expands whole column once, only replaces column with next table
    //*My subpage table was under another table, you will probably not need this line*   
    TempExpand1 = Table.ExpandTableColumn(TableToExpand, ColumnName, {"page"}, {"subpages.page"}),

    //Get Cell for this iteration, the expansion table of the Cell
    Cell = TempExpand1{ActualRowNumber}[subpages.page],

    CanExpandCell = if Cell is table then true else false,

    //*This just fixes up the data types. You will need to edit or delete this.*
    ExpandedTable = if CanExpandCell = true
                      then
                      Table.TransformColumnTypes(Cell,{{"uri.ui", type text}, {"title", type text}, {"namespace", type text}, {"date.created", type datetime}, {"language", type text}, {"Attribute:id", Int64.Type}, {"Attribute:guid", type text}, {"Attribute:draft.state", type text}, {"Attribute:href", type text}, {"Attribute:deleted", type logical}})
                      else
                      Cell,

    //If there was nothing to be expanded, just go to the next iteration
    //Otherwise, Append ExpandedTable to TableToExpand,
    NewTable = if CanExpandCell = false
                 then
                 TableToExpand                         
                 else
                 Table.Combine({TableToExpand, Cell}),

    //If the row number is now greater than the number of row in the table
    //Then return the table as it is
    //Else call the ExpandAndAppend function recursively with the expanded table
    NewRowNumber = ActualRowNumber + 1,
    OutputTable = if NewRowNumber>(Table.RowCount(NewTable)-1) 
                    then 
                    NewTable
                    else 
                    ExpandAndAppend(NewTable, NewRowNumber)
    in
    OutputTable
in
Source
```

Hopefully it makes some sort of sense. Obviously, if anyone else needs it, it will need to be modified. I wanted to make sure that my solution was documented since I wasn't able to find the answer elsewhere online.